# Summarizing a pandas DataFrame by calculating product

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to change the frequency on a pandas DataFrame by calculating the product of each rolling window.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [random.random() for i in range(10)]
},
    index=[date.today() + timedelta(i) for i in range(10)]
)
                   a
2020-07-30  0.352619
2020-07-31  0.778134
2020-08-01  0.094192
2020-08-02  0.111958
2020-08-03  0.619847
2020-08-04  0.573964
2020-08-05  0.120369
2020-08-06  0.075018
2020-08-07  0.647727
2020-08-08  0.717462
```

My desired output is something like this:

```
2020-07-30  0.274384
2020-08-01  0.010545
2020-08-03  0.355769
2020-08-05  0.009029
2020-08-07  0.464719
```

I tried to do it using `.asfreq('2D')` and `.rolling(window=2, min_periods=1)` but I can't apply `asfreq` to a rolling object:

```py
df['a'].rolling(window=2, min_periods=1).asfreq('1D').product()

AttributeError: 'Rolling' object has no attribute 'asfreq'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you don't want `rolling`, but rather `asfreq` or `resample`:

```
df.resample('2D').prod()
```

Output:

```
                   a
2020-07-30  0.274385
2020-08-01  0.010546
2020-08-03  0.355770
2020-08-05  0.009030
2020-08-07  0.464720
```

---

**Update**: Generally, you can use `groupby()` like this:

```
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//N).prod()
```

But then you get a dataframe with RangeIndex. To preserve the time index, you can do:

```
(df.reset_index().groupby(np.arange(len(df))//N)
   .agg({'index':'first', 'a':'prod'})
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting this TypeError: `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'` Indexes are date objects. What am I missing?

Comment: Do `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` before `resample`.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing based on a specified number of rows? for example, using an integer index, resampling every two consecutive rows?

Comment: Can you elaborate on `'index':'first'`?

Comment: that select the first instance of *column* `index` in the group. You can also use `'index': 'min'`, which selects the minimum.